# How to map values in a list to a pandas dataframe with binary values

Tags: pandas, mapping

I have a nested list with string values that I used to create a list with binary values. I used the transformed list as predictors in my model.

The list with string values -

```
D = [["An", "Cn"], ["Bs", "Gt"], ["Cd", "El"], ["Cd", "Cn", "En"]]
```

With

```
D_tran = pd.Series([';'.join(i) for i in D]).str.get_dummies(';')
```

I obtained `D_tran`

```
   An  Bs  Cd  Cn  El  En  Gt
0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
2   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
3   0   0   1   1   0   1   0
```

With

```
D_list = D_tran.values.tolist()
```

I obtained D_list:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

I use this to create a linear regression model. To test my model, however, I need to transform the string values in my test data to be binary. The test data looks like -

```
R = [["Bs"], ["Cd", "El"], ["An"]]
```

My question is how to map `R` into the frame of `D_list` in order to obtain

```
R = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Please note that, in the test data, only part of the predictors appear.

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can essentially do the same procedure as before with one minor modification: after creating the dummies dataframe, use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with the columns of `D_tran`:

```
R_tran = pd.Series([';'.join(i) for i in R]).str.get_dummies(';')
R_tran = R_tran.reindex(columns=D_tran.columns, fill_value=0)
R_list = R_tran.values.tolist()
```